# Combining different data frames with ID column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the follwing data frames
Data1 region 1

```
SID chr beta pval

Rs500 21 0.45 0.005
```

Data 2 region 2

```
SID chr beta pval

Rs500 21 0.7 0.007
```

Data3 region 3

```
SID  chr  beta  pval

Rs500 21 0.57 0.003
```

I want to combine data as
Data

```
SID  chr beta pval region

Rs500 21 0.45  0.005 region1

Rs500 21 0.7   0.007 region 2

Rs500 21 0.57. 0.003 region 3
```

Anyone can help with the code in r or linux
Thanks chuchu

Comment: In R you can do `dplyr::bind_rows(Data1, Data2, Data3, .id = 'region')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First label your regions so that you can tell which region the data comes from.

```
data1$region <- 'Region 1'
data2$region <- 'Region 2'
data3$region <- 'Region 3'
```

Then combine:

```
rbind(data1, data2, data3)
```

Comment: Thaks a lot otto it works, stay safe and Blessed !

Comment: Glad to have helped! Could I ask you to approve my answer?